# I have al list of lists. I want to remove several elements from every list

Tags: python, list, nested

here's my first attempt:

```
successes = 0
failures = 0
blacklist = ['Team', 'Range', 'm-boot', 'b']

for dial in dials:
    for value in dial:
        if value in blacklist:
            dial.remove(value)

for dial in dials:
    for item in dial:
        if item in blacklist:
            failures = failures + 1
        else:
            successes = successes + 1

print(f'number of removed strings: {successes}')
print(f'number of strings remain unremoved: {failures}')
```

Output:

```
number of removed strings: 7914
number of strings remain unremoved: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Perfect!  But I need to remove many more strings.  Add one more to the blacklist:

```
successes = 0
failures = 0
blacklist = ['Team', 'Range', 'm-boot', 'b', '/b']

for dial in dials:
    for value in dial:
        if value in blacklist:
            dial.remove(value)

for dial in dials:
    for item in dial:
        if item in blacklist:
            failures = failures + 1
        else:
            successes = successes + 1
print(f'number of removed strings: {successes}')
print(f'number of strings remain unremoved: {failures}')
```

aaaand:

```
number of removed strings: 7722
number of strings remain unremoved: 54

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can just tell you, the code isn't removing any instance of 'Team' and 'Range' each of which occur exactly once in each dial.  I'm just a beginner, here, so go easy on me?

edit:
everyone seems to think it's an issue with remove() stopping after one occurrence.  This makes no sense to me.  First, it is within a loop, checking only one value within that loop, so if the value matches, it removes it, if it doesn't, it leaves it, then the loop restarts, and the code issues remove() again, with no knowledge of prior successes or failures.  You can see that this is functioning as I expected, by looking at the number of successes and failures in the first attempt.  It is clearly removing all instances of items in the blacklist, but in attempt #2, it is just deciding not to search for Team, or Range.  Something I didn't mention, is that it stops sorting for those two strings no matter what index number they have in the blacklist.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi, so `remove` will only remove the first occurrence. To remove all perhaps filter the original list.

Answer (score 1):

so since `remove` only removes the first occurrence of the value in the list, it may leave additional matches intact. So you could instead reconstruct the list by filtering out the unwanted elements with a list comprehension:

```
# Define a set of blacklisted values
blacklist = {'Team', 'Range', 'm-boot', 'b', '/b'}

# Filter out the elements that are in the blacklist
dials = [[val for val in dial if val not in blacklist] for dial in dials]
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.  Thank you very much,  I need to understand list comprehensions better.  I'm still very confused as to why my solution didn't work.  Your's is clearly much cleaner, but something is happening that I don't understand and I wish I did.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `list.remove(x)` is case-sensetive w.r.t. string `x` and if `x` occurs more than once [it will only remove the first occurance](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html)

It also doesn't make sense to count how many removals have been done (second loop) **after** those elements have been removed (first loop). You should do the removing and the counting in the same loop:

```
# example list of lists
dials = [['a','b','Team','Team'],['c','d','e'],['Team', 'Range', 'm-boot', 'b']]
blacklist = ['Team', 'Range', 'm-boot', 'b']
dials_clean = []
successes = 0    
for dial in dials:
    for value in dial:
        if value in blacklist:
            dial = [d for d in dial if d != value] # remove all occurances of value
            successes = successes + 1
    dials_clean.append(dial)
print(str(successes)+" blacklisted items have been removed")

print("dials = "+str(dials_clean))

# if you want a proof that you had no failures you can add this:
failures = 0
for dial in dials_clean:
    for value in dial:
        if value in blacklist:
            failures +=1 
print("number of failures (should be zero): "+str(failures))
```

Answer (score 0):

It may occur in case there is more than one blacklist's element in your list, so `remove` just removes the first match. to have a list with unique values cast your `list` as `set` then remove. hence the removed element no longer exists in your list. also instead of iterating the `dial` list I prefer to iterate the `blacklist` as it seems to be a shorter list.

```py
for dial in dials:
    dial = set(dial)
    for value in blacklist:
        if value in dial:
            dial.remove(value)
```